# Android : Parsing .epub file

Tags: java, android, android-activity, ebook-reader

I am creating a epub book reader app in android for my client. 
I am currently using [FolioReader](https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android) in my app, but it is not displaying images. Is there any other alternative to display .epub files in android.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Try EpubParser https://github.com/mertakdut/EpubParser

Comment: @SpringBreaker it is still not displaying images

Comment: @Redman Image are showing in incorrect way

Comment: check if you are passing correct image path

Comment: @Ravi did you use epublib?

Comment: @Redman images not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extract images and keep a reference to those images while loading data in webview  . Try this code (add epub lib and slf4j libraries)

```
      outPutFolder=getDir("example", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) + "/"+fileName +"/" ;
          //your directory name

  try {

        epubInputStream=new FileInputStream(filePath);

    } catch (IOException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {
        book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    outPutFolder=getDir("example", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) + "/"+fileName +"/" ;
    setOutPutFolder(outPutFolder);

    DownloadResource(outPutFolder);



    linezNew = "";
    Spine spine = book.getSpine();
    List<SpineReference> spineList = spine.getSpineReferences() ;
    int count = spineList.size();

    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; count > i; i++) {

        Resource res = spine.getResource(i);

        try {
            InputStream is = res.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    linezNew =   string.append(line + "\n").toString();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    linezNew = linezNew.replace("../", "");

    finalDataToLoad="<head><style>img{max-width: 100%; width:50%; height: 50%;}</style></head> "+linezNew;


  webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://" + outPutFolder, finalDataToLoad, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

and DownloadResource function is

```
    private void DownloadResource(String directory) {
    try {

        Resources rst = book.getResources();
        Collection<Resource> clrst = rst.getAll();
        Iterator<Resource> itr = clrst.iterator();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Resource rs = itr.next();

            if ((rs.getMediaType() == MediatypeService.JPG)
                    || (rs.getMediaType() == MediatypeService.PNG)
                    || (rs.getMediaType() == MediatypeService.GIF)) {

                Log.d("Href", rs.getHref());

                File oppath1 = new File(directory, rs.getHref().replace("OEBPS/", ""));

                oppath1.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                oppath1.createNewFile();

                System.out.println("Path : "+oppath1.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath());


                FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream(oppath1);
                fos1.write(rs.getData());
                fos1.close();

            } else if (rs.getMediaType() == MediatypeService.CSS) {

                File oppath = new File(directory, rs.getHref());

                oppath.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                oppath.createNewFile();

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(oppath);
                fos.write(rs.getData());
                fos.close();

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

here filePath is path to your epub file ,fileName is name of your epub file which are Strings

outPutFolder,linezNew,finalDataToLoad are also Strings